Pyrogram connection timed out
I'm currently trying to launch a pyrogram user bot inside of corporate infrastructure, and my connection is getting timed out.
On my computer, everything works fine; we have access to the Telegram API and open ports 443 and 5222, disabled the proxy for the machine trying to start up the bot, but still nothing. I and the company I work for have access to Telegram, so it's not a location issue. Could this be because of a slow connection speed (the machine is quite laggy), or is there some kind of SSL error behind the scenes?
Previously, I've used a telebot and had to turn on SSL verification for the bot to work. The only purpose of the bot is to forward messages from other bots.
